# How do I hide variable/function names from debuggers?

Tags: c++, assembly, dll, reverse-engineering

I've created a .DLL in C++. The .DLL handles a lot of my programs core functionality and needs to be as secure and difficult as possible to understand. I have already packed it using a packer.

However, I'm noticing that when I open the .DLL in OllyDBG all of the variable names and Function names are still visible...

For example I can see this

```
MOV [VariableName], EAX
```

I would like to make it so [VariableName] is not displayed in such a obvious fashion.. Perhaps something more like....

```
MOV DWORD PTR DS:[ESI], EAX
```

I know there must be a way to do this as I don't see software out there having VariableNames and FunctionNames displaying for everyone to see...

Does anyone have any suggestions, I've already tried deleting the PDB that was created when the .DLL was built... Changed nothing.

Comment: Sounds like you are building a "debug" version of the dll.  I would double check to make sure you build a "release" version.  In visual studio this is a drop-down selection.

Comment: Downvoted for three reasons. (1) There are lots and lots of questions about code obfuscators on this site. (2) What's the point? If you have contracts and non-disclosure agreements, those hold a lot of sway. If you don't, you should. (3) If you're sending your .dll to a disreputable client, why are you doing that? They'll decompile and deobfuscate your obfuscated and compiled code faster than fast.

Comment: Steven, I am actually building it in Release mode.

David, the .DLL is distributed as part of a Game Client. That is why it is not pointless.

Answer (score 3):

If you are building with VC++, variable and function names are stored in the .pdb file --- pdb stands for "Program Database".  As Steve Hansen says, this is disabled by default in release builds; however, it is a [good practice](http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jrobbins/correctly-creating-native-c-release-build-pdbs) to enable it.  Just delete the .pdb file and OllyDBG should no longer display the variable and function names.

However, the names of functions exported from the DLL would still be visible, e.g. `dumpbin /exports mydll.dll` unless you [exported the functions by ordinal, in the .def file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyx1zcd3.aspx).

Comment: I've deleted the .pdf file and they continue to display...

Might it be that Olly stored them in some kind of save and that's why they keep showing?

Comment: Lol typo, I meant I deleted the pdb. The one that was built with the .DLL in the Release folder.

Comment: Are you sure?  If the .pdb file is deleted, then OllyDbg View | View Source Files window is empty....  Also, in the directory where OllyDbg.exe is, it creates .udd files for all your modules.  Try to delete those.

Comment: Perfect! That did the trick, I didn't realize Olly made those files. Deleting the .pdb and the olly .udd files was the solution.